# Is it possible to declare a static constexpr/inline member variable of a class within that class?

Tags: c++

I have created a sort of adapter class that serves no other purpose than to implicitly convert from functionally identical enums in two different libraries to an internal representation.

I would also like this class to emulate the functionality of an enum via `static constexpr` member variables if possible. C++20's `using enum` declaration could alleviate this issue, but I am unfortunately stuck with C++17 for the time being. That being said, it seems that while the following is valid:

```cpp
class Fruit {
    ...
public:
    static const Fruit APPLE;
};

const Fruit Fruit::APPLE(0);
```

Replacing `const` with either `constexpr` or `const inline` in the declaration produces an error because `Fruit` is must be a complete type in order to satisfy the requirements of a LiteralType. I would much prefer that these pseudo-enumerators be inlined, but it's starting to seem like that is not a possibility. Is there another way to achieve this I haven't thought of?

Comment: Why do you want it this way? What's the underlying problem you are trying to solve? Could you put the statics in a namespace instead of a class? Will there be non staric "fruits" (or whatever class its an abstraction of).

Comment: Inside the class, the class is incomplete. how about constexpr function? Something like: `static constexpr Fruit APPLE() { constexpr Fruit fruit{0}; return fruit; }`.

Comment: Why is it important that they're inlined? (in C++17 it has a specific meaning, "not linked" or something, can't remember. If it's just for optimization, compilers are probably already doing that)